# Finding the closest departure time C

Tags: c

I'm trying to find out how to get the closest departure time depending on what the user enters. The user can enter a 24-hour time, and the program will find the closest departure time in 12-hour time. Here are the departure and arrival times:

8:00 AM - 10:16 AM

9:43 AM - 11:52 AM

11:19 AM - 1:31 PM

12:47 PM - 3:00 PM

2:00 PM - 4:08 PM

3:45 PM - 5:55 PM

7:00 PM - 9:20 PM

9:45 PM - 11:58 PM

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int hour, minute, totalTime;

    printf("Enter a 24-hour timer: ");
    scanf("%d:%d", &hour, &minute);

    totalTime = (hour * 60) + minute; /*Calculating the amount of minutes*/

    if (totalTime <= 480)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 8:00 a.m., arriving at 10:16 a.m.\n");
    } 
    else if (totalTime <= 583 && totalTime > 480)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 9:43 a.m., arriving at 11:52 a.m.\n");
    }

    if (totalTime <= 679 && totalTime > 583)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 11:19 a.m., arriving at 1:31 p.m.\n");
    } 
    else if (totalTime <= 767 && totalTime > 679)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 12:47 p.m., arriving at 3:00 p.m.\n");
    }
    if (totalTime <= 840 && totalTime > 767)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 2:00 p.m., arriving at 4:08 p.m.\n");
    } 
    else if (totalTime <= 945 && totalTime > 840)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 3:45 p.m., arriving at 5:55 p.m.\n");
    }
    if (totalTime <= 1140 && totalTime > 945)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 7:00 p.m., arriving at 9:20 p.m.\n");
    } 
    else if (totalTime <= 1305 && totalTime > 1140)
    {
        printf("Closest depature time is 9:45 p.m., arriving at 11:58 p.m.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm unsure on how I can approach this, like if I enter 13:15, how can I make sure it goes to 12:47 PM and not 2:00 PM as it does now. All the times that are in the if statements (like 480), is just the hour 8:00 AM calculated into minutes. I'd also like to know how I can optimise this and get rid of all these if statements,

Comment: Try using functions from `time.h`. You can fill structure `tm` and then, use function `difftime` to get time difference. The smallest one will be the one that is closest to your value.

Comment: You need to encode the data you’re given into an array of structures which you can then search.  You shouldn’t have to do more than change the array of new times are given.  Indeed, if you read the data from a file, the program should not need to change at all.  Remember that 11:55 am occurs 11 hours after 12:55 am.  What happens when someone enters at time like 01:00 or 05:00 in 24-hour notation?

Answer (score 1):

Convert each 12 hour AM/PM time into minutes of the day.

Special concern when the `hour == 12`.

```
int minute_of_the_day(int hour, int min, int ispm) {
  if (hour >= 12) hour -= 12;  // Make 12:01 AM as 0:01 AM,  same for PM
  return (hour + ispm*12)*60 + min;
}
```

Form a table of departure times

```
typedef struct {
  int hour, min, ispm;
} hmp;

#define AM 0
#define PM 1
hmp depart[] = { {8,0,AM}, {9,43,AM}, {11,19,AM} ....five more };
```

Search the times. `<=` below is going on the idea the the closest *next* departure is the goal, not the closest departure - do that later.

```
// reference time from 24 hour time
int totalTime = (hour * 60) + minute;

int n = sizeof depart/sizeof depart[0];
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  int depart_time = minute_of_the_day(depart[i].hour, depart[i].min, depart[i].ispm);
  if (totalTime <= depart_time) {
    break;
  }
}
if (i == n) i = 0;
```

We now have the index `i` of departure time that leave on or after `totalTime`.  Now find closest.

```
// Form previous index
int h = i - 1;
if (h < 0) h += n; 

int depart_time0 = minute_of_the_day(depart[h].hour, depart[h].min, depart[h].ispm);
int depart_time1 = minute_of_the_day(depart[i].hour, depart[i].min, depart[i].ispm);

 // Form differences from totalTime to the 2 departure times.
 // Account for end-of-day roll-over.
 int delta0 = (totalTime - depart_time0 + 24*60)%(24*60);
 int delta1 = (depart_time0 - totalTime + 24*60)%(24*60);

int best_index = delta0 < delta1 ? h : i;

const char *ampm[2] = { "AM", "PM" };
printf("Leave at %d:%02d %s\n", 
    depart[best_index].hour, depart[best_index].min, ampm[depart[best_index].ispm]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find two closest values
2. Find the difference with each of them
3. Compare the differences and find the shortest

---

1. 13:15 = (12:47, 2:00)
2. - 3. absolute(12:47 - 13:15) <= absolute(12:47 - 2:00)

Comment: "closest departure time" does imply _absolute difference_, yet surely if the flight left 10 minutes ago, the next one is the closest departure time in the future is the goal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica check the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/59921433/11964634
just as he wanted " like if I enter 13:15, how can I make sure it goes to 12:47 PM and not 2:00 PM as it does now"

Answer (score 0):

Can you use libraries? If so, use `time.h`.
Else, convert times into distance from 00:00 in minutes.
Once you have that it just turns into a problem of finding the closest number.

Comment: Can't use any other headers other than stdio.h

Answer (score 0):

use `fgets` and `sscanf_s` for safer handling of user inputs. You can use a `switch` statement instead of `if` statements but using ranges in the `case` conditions is non-standard C. You don't need to use parenthesis' in `if` statements if there is only one line of code following each condition, which can help shorten the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long hour, minute, totalTime;
    char buf[10];

    printf("Enter a 24-hour timer: ");
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
    sscanf_s(buf, "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);

    totalTime = (hour * 60) + minute; /*Calculating the amount of minutes*/

    if (totalTime <= 480)
        printf("Closest depature time is 8:00 a.m., arriving at 10:16 a.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 480 && totalTime <= 583)
        printf("Closest depature time is 9:43 a.m., arriving at 11:52 a.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 583 && totalTime <= 679)
        printf("Closest depature time is 11:19 a.m., arriving at 1:31 p.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 679 && totalTime <= 767)
        printf("Closest depature time is 12:47 p.m., arriving at 3:00 p.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 767 && totalTime <= 840)
        printf("Closest depature time is 2:00 p.m., arriving at 4:08 p.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 840 && totalTime <= 945)
        printf("Closest depature time is 3:45 p.m., arriving at 5:55 p.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 945 && totalTime <= 1140)
        printf("Closest depature time is 7:00 p.m., arriving at 9:20 p.m.\n");
    else if (totalTime > 1140 && totalTime <= 1305)
        printf("Closest depature time is 9:45 p.m., arriving at 11:58 p.m.\n");
    else 
        printf("No depatures at this time.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The time 13:15 corresponds to 795 minutes, so the `if` condition for this time range would in fact be `"Closest depature time is 2:00 p.m., arriving at 4:08 p.m.\n"`. If that is incorrect, then you need to fix your conditions.

Comment: How is this safer then the code from OP? In what way is it safer? How does it address the OPs question `how I can optimise this and get rid of all these if statements`?

Comment: 13:15 PM is closer to 12:47 PM than 2:00 PM, so it needs to be "Closest departure time is 12:47 p.m., arriving at 3:00 p.m."

Comment: @icantprogram Then you need to fix the boundaries in the fourth `else if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can optimise this and get rid of all these if statements

1. Identify unique elements in all the if statements
2. Put all those elements in an array of structures.
3. Change if statements to looping over an array.

Generally, use a way to represent your data. Represent it in a structure. Then iterate over an array of those structure to do the job.

```
// represents a hour and a minute
struct hourmin {
    unsigned hour; // hour, represented as 0 - 11
    unsigned min;  // minute, represented as 0 - 59
    char am; // equal to 'a' if a.m., 'p' if p.m.
    // you could also ex. represent hour as 0 - 23
};

// represents a flight - it's departure and arrival
struct flight {
   struct hourmin departure;
   struct hourmin arrival;
};

// converts a hour and a minute into minutes since noon
unsigned hourmin_to_minutes(struct hourmin hm) {
    return (hm.hour + hm.am == 'a' ? 0 : 12) * 60 + hm.min;
}

// array of flights. Note: has to be sorted increasingly!
const struct flight flights[] = {
   // 8:00 AM - 10:16 AM
   { { 8, 0, 'a', }, { 10, 16, 'p', }, },
   // you could also use designed initializers
   // 9:43 AM - 11:52 AM
   { 
       .departure = { .hour = 9, .min = 0, .am = 'a', },
       .arrival = { .hour = 11, .min = 52, .am = 'a', },
   },
// etc....
// 11:19 AM - 1:31 PM
// 12:47 PM - 3:00 PM
// 2:00 PM - 4:08 PM
// 3:45 PM - 5:55 PM
// 7:00 PM - 9:20 PM
// 9:45 PM - 11:58 PM
};

int main() {
    // .. your code

    int found_idx = -1;
    const int flights_count = sizeof(flights)/sizeof(*flights);

    // iterate over datas and find the first departure greater then totaltime
    for (int i = 0; i < flights_count; ++i) {
        // flights are sorted, so we don't need to compare previous
        if (totaltime <= hourmin_to_minutes(flights[i].departure) {
            // if we find, we save index and break from the loop
            found_idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // found_idx is initialized with -1
    if (found_idx == -1) {
        printf("No depatures at this time.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Closest depature time is %02d:%02d %c.m., arriving at %02d:%02d %c.m.\n",
           flights[found_idx].departure.hour, 
           flights[found_idx].departure.min, 
           flights[found_idx].departure.am,
           flights[found_idx].arrival.hour, 
           flights[found_idx].arrival.min, 
           flights[found_idx].arrival.am
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a whole working app with every and each request you made. Just copy and paste, compile and study. I'd appreciate your appreciation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned char byte;
enum {AM, PM, None};
ushort flights[8][2][3] = {
    {{8,0,AM},{10,16,AM}},
    {{9,43,AM},{11,52,AM}},
    {{11,19,AM},{1,31,PM}},
    {{12,47,PM},{3,0,PM}},
    {{2,0,PM},{4,8,PM}},
    {{3,45,PM},{5,55,PM}},
    {{7,0,PM},{9,20,PM}},
    {{9,45,PM},{11,58,PM}}
};
byte get_formated_time(char* time, ushort* formated){
    size_t len = strlen(time);
    if(len > 7 || len < 3) return 0;
    const char *ptr = strchr(time,':');
    if(!ptr) return 0;
    byte index = ptr - time;
    if(index < 1 || index > 2) return 0;
    char holder[2];
    memcpy(holder, time, index);
    for(byte i = 0; i < 2 && holder[i] != 0; i++)
        if(!isdigit(holder[i])) return 0;
    ushort hours = (ushort)atoi(holder);
    ushort mins = 3;
    short meridiem = None;
    char m, _m;
    switch(len - index++ - 1){
        case 1:
            if(!isdigit(time[index])) return 0;
            holder[0] = time[index]; holder[1] = 0;
            mins = (ushort)atoi(holder);
            break;
        case 2:
            for(byte i = index; i < index + 2; i++){
                if(!isdigit(time[i])) return 0;
                holder[i - index] = time[i];
            }
            mins = (ushort)atoi(holder);
            break;
        case 3:
            mins = 2;
        case 4:
            m = time[index + mins];
            _m = time[index + mins - 1];
            if( m != 'M' && m != 'm' 
                || _m != 'P' && _m != 'A'
                && _m != 'a' && _m != 'p') return 0;
            for(byte i = index; i < index + mins - 1; i++){
                if(!isdigit(time[i])) return 0;
                holder[i - index] = time[i];
            }
            meridiem = _m == 'P' || _m == 'p';
            if(mins == 2) holder[1] = 0;
            mins = (ushort)atoi(holder);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    if(meridiem == None && hours > 23
            || meridiem != None && (hours > 12 || hours == 0)
            || mins > 59) return 0;
    formated[0] = hours;
    formated[1] = mins;
    formated[2] = meridiem;
    return 1;
}
short minutes(ushort* time){
    short minutes = 0;
    switch (time[2])
    {
        case PM:
            if(time[0] != 12)
                minutes += 720;
        case None:
            minutes += time[0] * 60 + time[1];
            break;
        case AM:
            if(time[0] != 12)
                minutes = time[0] * 60;
            minutes += time[1];
            break;
    default:
        minutes = -1;
    }
    return minutes;
}
byte get_closest_departure(ushort* input){
    short time = minutes(input);
    byte flight = 0;
    ushort min_gap = -1;
    for(byte i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        ushort curr_gap = abs(minutes(flights[i][0]) - time);
        if(curr_gap < min_gap)
        {
            flight = i;
            min_gap = curr_gap;
        }
    }
    return flight;
}
int main(int argc, char**argv){
    printf("Enter the time delimeted by a colon: ");
    char *input;
    scanf("%ms", &input);
    ushort foramted_time[3];
    while (!get_formated_time(input, foramted_time))
    {
        printf("Wrong format\nEnter the time delimeted by a colon: ");
        scanf("%ms", &input);
    }
    free(input);
    byte flight = get_closest_departure(foramted_time);
    printf("Closest flight is: %hu:%hu%s - %hu:%hu%s\n",
        flights[flight][0][0],flights[flight][0][1],
        flights[flight][0][2] == AM ? "AM" : "PM",
        flights[flight][1][0],flights[flight][1][1],
        flights[flight][1][2] == AM ? "AM" : "PM");
    return 0;
}
```